# BASH dialog Dynamic menu

Tags: linux, bash, dynamic, dialog

I need to create a dynamic menu with dialog using vars from an array.

Heres my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
file="teste.cfg"
count=0;
while IFS=";" read nomeTarefa dirOrigem dirDest tipoBkp agendarBkp compactarBkp gerarLog || [[ -n "$gerarLog" ]]; do #RECEBE NAS VARS OS VALORES DELIMITADOS POR ;
    count=$((count + 1));#INICIA O COUNT PARA INCREMENTAR O OPTIONS
    options[$count]="$options$count) \"$nomeTarefa\"" #CONCATENA O OPTIONS

done < $file

options=$"$options"

for ((i=1; i<=count; i++))
do
    echo ${options[$i]}
done

options=(${options[$count]}) 

cmd=(dialog --keep-tite --menu "Select options:" 22 76 16)

choices=$("${cmd[@]}" "${options[@]}" 2>&1 >/dev/tty)
```

I recieve vars from a file, and then i need to build the "options" dynamicly to create a case.

So this menu dialog, will have x numbers of entries and when i run any of them i do something.

Any ideas how can i build this "options"?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just solved guys.

```
#!/bin/bash
file="teste.cfg"
count=0;
while IFS=";" read nomeTarefa dirOrigem dirDest tipoBkp agendarBkp compactarBkp gerarLog || [[ -n "$gerarLog" ]]; do #RECEBE NAS VARS OS VALORES DELIMITADOS POR ;
        count=$((count + 1));#INICIA O COUNT PARA INCREMENTAR O OPTIONS 
    options[$count]=$count") \"$nomeTarefa\"" #CONCATENA O OPTIONS  
done < $file ##END READ FILE

options=(${options[@]})

cmd=(dialog --keep-tite --menu "Select options:" 22 76 16)

choices=$("${cmd[@]}" "${options[@]}" 2>&1 >/dev/tty)
```

Thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

Oddly, the solution listed here did not work for me. The `${options[@]}` array required the following (rather strange) structure in order to work. This was tested on bash in Ubuntu 18.04:

```
 #Dynamic dialogs require an array that has a staggered structure
 #array[1]=1
 #array[2]=First_Menu_Option
 #array[3]=2
 #array[4]=Second_Menu_Option
```

Here is bash code that reads in a directory listing from an argument and creates a dynamic menu from it:

```
 #! /bin/bash
 #usage: Dynamic_Menu.bash /home/user/target_directory     

 declare -a array

 i=1 #Index counter for adding to array
 j=1 #Option menu value generator

 while read line
 do     
    array[ $i ]=$j
    (( j++ ))
    array[ ($i + 1) ]=$line
    (( i=($i+2) ))

 done < <(find $1 -type f) #consume file path provided as argument

 #Define parameters for menu
 TERMINAL=$(tty) #Gather current terminal session for appropriate redirection
 HEIGHT=20
 WIDTH=76
 CHOICE_HEIGHT=16
 BACKTITLE="Back_Title"
 TITLE="Dynamic Dialog"
 MENU="Choose a file:"

 #Build the menu with variables & dynamic content
 CHOICE=$(dialog --clear \
                 --backtitle "$BACKTITLE" \
                 --title "$TITLE" \
                 --menu "$MENU" \
                 $HEIGHT $WIDTH $CHOICE_HEIGHT \
                 "${array[@]}" \
                 2>&1 >$TERMINAL)
```